# Checking Endianness of RISC-V machine using C-code

Tags: c, riscv

Can someone please help me out with this. There is a C-code which most of you are familiar with, it checks the endian-ness of a machine.

What would be the result if it runs on a RISC-V machine?

Code is mentioned as below:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    char* p = (char*)&x;
    printf("%d\n",(int)*p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically that breaks strict aliasing. You either have to copy the `int` value to a `char` buffer, or use a `union` for type-punning. With that said, how would a four-byte integer be stored in memory on a little-endian system? How would it be stored on a bit-endian system? If you know how it would be stored on a little-endian system, just reverse it for the big-endian system and you have the result.

Comment: Oh and I recommend you print it as an 8-digit hexadecimal value instead, that way it will be easier to see what bits might be set. Use the `"%08x"` format for that, and use an `unsigned int` for the value instead.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that breaks strict aliasing.  It is explicitly permitted to access the value of an object of any type via an lvalue of character type.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V#Memory_access), RISC-V's native byte order is little-endian.

Answer (score 3):

The program is valid regardless of the platform.
The output is `1` for a little-endian computer *or* a computer where `sizeof (int)` == `sizeof (char)`. It will be `0` for all other platforms.

Since RISC-V is little-endian then the output should be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Really, it's the compiler's responsibility to tell you such fundamental things (which are known at compile time), and you shouldn't have to rely on such runtime memory-cast shenanigans to figure it out.

For C, gcc (and thus clang) defines [preprocessor macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__` and `__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__` which tell you.

Visual C doesn't, but MS says "All native scalar types are little-endian for the platforms that Microsoft Visual C++ targets (x86, x64, ARM, ARM64)" [(ref)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/bit-enum?view=msvc-170).  So really it's safe to assume that if `_MSC_VER` is defined, you're little endian.

```
#if defined __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ || defined _MSC_VER
  printf("little\n");
#else
#  if defined __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
     printf("big\n");
#  else
#    error "unknown endian-ness"
#  endif
#endif
```

This will break if MS releases some future MSVC for some future architecture that is big endian. While I'm all for robust code, I don't think it's fair to expect code you're writing now to work on imaginary environments.

For C++, things are properly standardised from C++20 with `std::endian` [(ref)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian), which is determined at compile time (constexpr).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following program on my VisionFive 2 RISC-V SBC from StarFive.

```
// test the endiness type for the architecture
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long  x = 1;
    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&x;
    printf(" if 1 then little-endian %d\n",(unsigned long)*p);

#if defined(__BYTE_ORDER__)
#if defined(__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__) && (__BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__)
    printf("  __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__ defined\n");
#elif defined(__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__) && (__BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
    printf("  __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ defined\n");
#else
    printf("  defines not set.\n");
#endif
#else
    printf("  No __BYTE_ORDER__ define found.\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and ran the program, the following output was displayed:

```
user@starfive:~/Documents$ ./a.out
 if 1 then little-endian 1
  __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ defined
user@starfive:~/Documents$
```

The [gcc Common Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) says the usage for these defines is:

> **BYTE_ORDER**
>
> **ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN**
>
> **ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN**
>
> **ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN**
>
> **BYTE_ORDER** is defined to one of the values **ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN**, **ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN**, or **ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN** to reflect the layout of multi-byte and multi-word quantities in
> memory. If **BYTE_ORDER** is equal to **ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN** or
> **ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN**, then multi-byte and multi-word quantities are laid out identically: the byte (word) at the lowest address is the
> least significant or most significant byte (word) of the quantity,
> respectively. If **BYTE_ORDER** is equal to **ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN**, then
> bytes in 16-bit words are laid out in a little-endian fashion, whereas
> the 16-bit subwords of a 32-bit quantity are laid out in big-endian
> fashion.
>
> You should use these macros for testing like this:
>
> /* Test for a little-endian machine */
>
> #if **BYTE_ORDER** == **ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN**